# Convert Java variable containing newline to javascript variable

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I want to convert a java variable(containing newline and other special characters) from server side sent to JSP to javascript variable.

In my JSP,

```
var test = '${educationDescription}';
alert(test);
```

Value of educationDescription sent from server side is

```
    This is
test
containing newline
and other special chars like " & ; etc
```

But I am getting javascript error for the above code snippet.

Comment: You already did it. What is your question ?

Comment: Hi Suresh, I am getting javascript error for the above code since in javascript, its a string var spanning in more than 1 line.

Comment: As this is a variable which is containing new lines, you need to escape new line.

Comment: Have you tried using StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript from Apache's common-lang lib?

Comment: @Jai I gave an answer :) Can you check and let me know ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue I faced long back and very irritated with javascript as well for no proper error message.

Later I managed to solve by replacing all catridges like below from Java string.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

'${fn.replace(educationDescription,"\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "")';
```

It solves the issue.

The issue here is with, we assume the problem is with new line. But sometimes the String comes with a brand new catride `\r` which many people not aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Use two slashes ("`\\n`")

```
<%
String s = "This is a \\n test";
request.setAttribute("s", s);
%>

var s="${s}";
alert(s);
```